# change Unix(Epoch) time to local time in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, timezone, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, epoch

I have a dataframe in Spark which contains Unix(Epoch) time and also   timezone name. I hope to convert the epochtime to local time according to different tz  name.
Here is how my data looks like:

```
data = [
    (1420088400, 'America/New_York'),
    (1420088400, 'America/Los_Angeles'),
    (1510401180, 'America/New_York'),
    (1510401180, 'America/Los_Angeles')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["epoch_time", "tz_name"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df1 = spark.sql("""select *, from_unixtime(epoch_time) as gmt_time,"
               from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(epoch_time), tz_name) as local_time"
               from df""")
df1.show(truncate= False)
```

Here is the result:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|epoch_time|tz_name            |gmt_time           |local_time           |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|1420088400|America/New_York   |2015-01-01 05:00:00|2015-01-01 00:00:00.0|
|1420088400|America/Los_Angeles|2015-01-01 05:00:00|2014-12-31 21:00:00.0|
|1510401180|America/New_York   |2017-11-11 11:53:00|2017-11-11 06:53:00.0|
|1510401180|America/Los_Angeles|2017-11-11 11:53:00|2017-11-11 03:53:00.0|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

1. I'm not quite sure if this transfer is right, but it seems the daylight saving has been taking care of.
2. Should I first change epochtime to time string using from_unixtime, then change it to utc timestamp using  to_utc_timestamp, finally change this UTC timestamp to local time with tz_name? Tried this but got error

   ```
   df2 = spark.sql("""select *, from_unixtime(epoch_time) as gmt_time,
                      from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(epoch_time), tz_name) as local_time,
                      from_utc_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(epoch_time),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'z')), tz_name) as newtime from df""")
   ```
3. How could I check my EMR server timezone?
4. Tried use , is this the server timezone?

   ```
   spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'z')").show()
   ```

   which gave me:

   ```
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp(), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), z)|
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                                       UTC|
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```

Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: What was the error? Works fine for me.

Comment: what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Spark 2.0 .  I checked it on EMR console   https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1  where region is us-east-1. How could I check server time zone name?

Comment: Do you know spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'z')")   'z' represents for?

Answer (score 5):

When you call `from_unixtime` it will format the date based on your Java runtime's timezone, since it's just using the default timezone for `SimpleDateFormat` [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L523). In your case it's UTC. So when you convert the values to local time you would only need to call `from_utc_timestamp` with the `tz_name` value passed in. However if you were to change your system timezone then you would need to call `to_utc_timestamp` first.

Spark 2.2 introduces a timezone setting so you can set the timezone for your SparkSession like so

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "GMT")
```

In which case the time functions will use `GMT` vs your system timezone, see source [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L715)

Comment: Thank you for your answer which explain part of  what I'm missing. Why I checked the EMR server from console it's us-east-1 region, but  from spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'z')").show()  it's UTC?   If I set  the timezone for my SparkSession, will that only within my current Spark session? If I stop this session in my code, when I start another session, I need to  set it again? Thanks.

Comment: you could set it in your spark config, for example for spark-shell use `--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=GMT`